# Проблема с Angular Http при отправке запроса

Tags: javascript, php, angular, angular4

Очень плохо разбираюсь в Angular, информации понятной практически нет, застрял на получении данных с БД с бэкэндом PHP.

код файла login.component.ts

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { FormGroup, FormControl, Validators } from '@angular/forms';
import {UserService} from "../../shared/servises/user.service";
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';
import {User} from "../../shared/models/user.model";

@Component({
  selector: 'app-login',
  templateUrl: './login.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./login.component.css']
})
export class LoginComponent implements OnInit {

  form: FormGroup;
  user: User;
  response: any;

  constructor(private http: HttpClient) { }

  ngOnInit() {
    //noinspection TypeScriptValidateTypes
    this.form = new FormGroup({
      'email': new FormControl(null, [Validators.required, Validators.email]),
      'password': new FormControl(null, [Validators.required, Validators.minLength(6)])
    })

    this.http.get('http://ng-everyday/php/test.php')
      .subscribe((response) => {
        this.response = response;
        console.log(this.response);
      })
  }

  onSubmit(){
    console.log(this.form);

  }
}
```

код файла php

```
<?php

header('Content-Type: application/json');
//подключение к базе данных на локальном хосте/

$pdo = new PDO("mysql:host=localhost; dbname=everyday; charset=utf8", 'admin', 'zihorka19836');
$pdo->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);


class User{

    function hasEmail($email, $pdo){
        //проверяем существует ли такой пользователь
        $sql = $pdo->query("SELECT * FROM `user` WHERE `user_mail` = '$email' LIMIT 1")->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

        return $sql;
    }//end hasEmail
}

    $mail = new User();
    $res = $mail->hasEmail('qq@qq.qq', $pdo);

        echo json_encode($res);
?>
```

Если PHP файл открываю в браузере получаю такую строку

```
 {"user_id":"177",
"user_name":"Vasa",
"user_mail":"qq@qq.qq",
"password":"50c512b0c6d70150831829ac68aa72a1",
"reg_date":"2018-10-20"}
```

а в итоге вылезает ошибка 
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 0):

Оказывается нужно было просто добавить заголовки header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *');

Но все же кто нибудь может порекомендовать инфу по Angular в работе с БД???